# (in a List Modify View, under Style) Difference between Default Table VS Basic Table

Tags: list

From my recent suffering, somehow changing it to 'Basic Table' fixed the issue.

I am happy that I see the status lights back to work in my current O365 site but at the same time, I am afraid that it will break other things.

What are the differences?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of the View Styles with screen shots: (a little dated, but still applies)

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/05/sharepoint-list-view-styles.html

Starting with SharePoint 2013, selecting any view but "Default" will hide the new command bar at the top of the list/library.